# Overwrite pixel in cocos2-d

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm writing with cocos2d-x, and have a problem:

For example, there are two sprites: a human and his clothes. I use fade (cascade opacity) to make it disappear, but during this the user can see the parts of the human body which were supposed to be hidden by the clothes. How to avoid this? How can I use render for that? Is there a way to overwrite pixels when render in cocos or OpenGL? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: You should try changing blending modes (in Cocos studio it's easy preview how it looks).

Comment: I don't use Cocos studio, and blending mode wouldn't help, as I think, because blending modes change all the images under this one, but I need some sprites under it not to be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCClippingNode to do the job.

CCClippingNode::create(cocos2d::CCNode *mask)  (2.x type)

CCClippingNode::setInverted(bool)

It is used to create a clipping region. And you can use it to cover the body. Add the body in the clippingNode by addChild and use cloth as mask.